# 401 Unauthorized when querying durable function status

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I need some help with Azure Durable Functions.

I created a new durable function with VS Code in C# and deployed it to Azure via the VS Code azure function extension. The function app resource was already created manually in the portal. I use

```
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: dotnet
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~2
```

I can trigger the creation of an durable task and but when I query the status with the **statusQueryGetUri**, I only get a 401 Unauthrized. The http trigger of the function itself is anonymous and does not require authentication (for debug purpose only).

The requests look like this (I used Postman to send the requests):

```
HTTP POST https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/api/SayHello_HttpStart
Response:
{
"id": "da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6",
"statusQueryGetUri": "https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6?taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g==",
"sendEventPostUri": "https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g==",
"terminatePostUri": "https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g==",
"rewindPostUri": "https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6/rewind?reason={text}&taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g==",
"purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6?taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g=="
}
```

The Get Request is then simply:

```
GET https://{function-app}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/da3259a462084e86a34f8ce9859a6ed6?taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage&code=ua4tHacVv9JDH5phKCJI1OdKGXQSB/MMUX8WIv1E0OyZANqrRY3L/g==
```

Did I miss some configuration I have to set to allow access to the uri? What logs might help me figure out what the problem is?

When I run the code locally there are no problems and everything works as expected.

Thanks a lot for all help!

Comment: Can you show how did you send the request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the statusQueryGetUri is an admin endpoint which always requires a System Key.

```
GET <rootUrl>/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/<GUID>
?taskHub={taskHub}
&connection={connection}
&code={systemKey}
```

As an alternative, you could also set the `x-functions-key` header of the http request with this key.

More info on the usage of the HTTP endpoints [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api).